# In R package workflow how to add image to shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-package

I have problems to understand this behavior:

I have a small shiny app organized in a package workflow like described [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html):

1. Put all R code in the R/ directory.
2. Write a function that starts your app (i.e. calls shinyApp() with your UI and server).
3. Create a DESCRIPTION file in the root directory of your app.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

myApp <- function(...) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Minimal Shiny App"),
    
    mainPanel(
      div(
        style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
        sliderInput("slider", "Slider", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
        tags$img(src = "logo.png", width = 200, style = "margin-left: 20px;")
      ),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:input$slider, type = "l", lwd = 2)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, ...)
}

myApp()
```

**I would like to add the `logo.png` image to the app:**

##### 1. Using this code, I get this:

```
library(devtools)
load_all()
myApp()
```

[image]

##### 2. Using this code once, I get this:

```
runApp()
```

[image]

##### 3. If I use now `myApp()` (after I have used runApp() once in the app), I get this:

```
# After I used runApp() once before
myApp()
```

[image]

The `logo.png` file is in `www` folder in the `R` folder.

All works fine if I do not use the package workflow. But I need this workflow and for me it is not possible to get the image there when using `load_all()` and `myApp()`.

I have used `system.file` like `tags$img(src = system.file("R/www", "logo.png", package = "test2"), width = 200, style = "margin-left: 20px;"))` but same behaviour

Comment: I believe the www folder should be one level up, not under the R folder.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately not. Have tried all: `inst/www/logo.png`, `inst/app/www/logo.png`, `www/logo.png`, `R/www/logo.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be "Create a package which contains an R Shiny app".

Let's call the package "rabbit". This is my suggested file & folder arrangement:

```
|- .Rbuildignore
|- .Renviron
|- .Rprofile
|- data/
|- data-raw/
|- DESCRIPTION
|- rabbit.Rproj
|- inst/
    |- app/
        |- global.R
        |- R/
        |- server.R
        |- ui.R
        |- www/
|- NAMESPACE
|- R/
|- README.md
|- README.Rmd
|- tests/
```

You don't need to have all the files/folders listed above.

Now let's look at the important directories in regards to your question.

#### `R/`

This is the one at the root of the project folder (listed after `NAMESPACE` above).

Put all the business logic there. These are the functions which can be exported from your package.
These have nothing to do with the app.

It will also contain `run_rabbit.R` which is a function to run your app.

```r
#' Run the rabbit shiny app
#' 
#' @export
run_rabbit <- function() {
  # You can set options for your app here, eg.
  # Increase file upload size to 1GB:
  # options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 1e3 * 1024^2)
  
  app_dir <- system.file("app", package = "rabbit")
  if (app_dir == "") {
    stop(
      "Could not find the app directory. Try re-installing `rabbit`.",
      call. = FALSE
    )
  }
  setwd(app_dir)
  shiny::shinyAppDir(appDir = ".")
}
```

#### `inst/app/R/`

This is where your shiny modules and other helper functions related to
the app will reside.

#### `inst/app/www/`

You can put your CSS, JS and image files here.

To reference these in the app, you can:

```r
tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "styles.css")
```

Say you decide to put all images in one folder `inst/app/www/img/`, then you can:

```r
tags$img(
  src = file.path('img', 'rabbit-logo.svg')
)
```

where `rabbit-logo.svg` is your app's logo.

#### Run the app

```r
devtools::load_all()
run_rabbit()
```